# Emacs 23 window.el

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I am using emacs 23 on two computers.
On both, `dpkg -s emacs` outputs the following version number.
However one has `window.el` and the other not.  This make some function such as `split-window` behave differently.  The help page of this function on the computer that apparently has not `window.el` installed reads that it comes from `C source code` instead.

Where does this difference comes from?

I prefer the behaviour of the one that says that `split-window` comes from `window.el`: it allows to specify the SIDE when splitting window and provide additional function such as `window-resize`.
I suppose this is the most recent one but I do not know how to check it nor how to upgrade the other to this state.

Comment: You never did specify the package version, but of more interest is the Emacs version -- what does `M-x emacs-version` tell you on each machine? Also, if you run `emacs -Q` on both machines, is their behaviour still different from one other?

Comment: @phils The emacs version are indeed different.  It happened that `dpkg -s emacs` was not targeting the proper emacs installation.

Comment: @phils Add the command `M-x emacs-version` to your answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: How about copying the function you like from `windows.el` and pasting it to your `.emacs` file -- then, rename the function to `alfred-split-window` instead of `split-window` and you are done. Now, with either version of Emacs, just call `M-x alfred-split-window`.  You can even set up a keyboard shortcut, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Library `window.el` is as old as the hills.  Perhaps you meant that one of your Emacs installlations has `window.elc` but not `window.el`?

More likely, you are referring only to function `split-window`.  Yes, it used to be a built-in function (i.e., defined in C), and now it is defined in `window.el` (which file exists also for the older Emacs versions where that function is a built-in).

FYI, lots of window and buffer-display stuff was changed around the same time as `split-window` was rewritten in Lisp.  Lots of behaviors changed, in minor or major ways.

What is *not at all clear* is what the problem is that you are reporting.  You ask, "*Where does this difference comes from? How to fix it?"*  I've explained a bit about the difference.  As for how to fix it -- what is the "it" that needs fixing, and what would the fixed behavior be like?

IOW, your question is, so far, unanswerable.  If you specify things more exactly, perhaps we can help more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what's going on with your debian packages, but if memory serves the readable .el(.gz) files are not supplied in the basic package, but in a separate package. This is because all you strictly need is the byte-compiled .elc files, so they can reduce the base package filesize by omitting them (at the expense of enabling you to read the elisp code).

Is `M-x load-library RET window RET` successful?

Note that Emacs 24 is the current stable version. You might want to upgrade.

*Edit:*

`M-x emacs-version` tells you which version of Emacs you're running, which will always give you a definitive answer.

(And if the versions *are* identical, then run `emacs -Q` to eliminate and site- and user-specific config files from the picture, as those are always a likely culprit for differing behaviours.)

Comment: M-x load-library RET window RET is succesful but has no effect that I could notice.
I will probably upgrade to emacs 24 later on but for now I would like to have emacs working the same way at home and in my office.

Comment: Yes, that was just to confirm that the library *is* definitely there. (I wasn't expecting it to have an effect -- it should already have been loaded.)